# PHP funcion que compruebe si los campos de un array (clave/valor) son los esperados

Tags: php

estoy haciendo una funcion que me actualice un **familiar** pero no solo que actualice, sino que primero compruebe **si es un array** luego **si contiene unos campos determinados** y me esta un **resultado no esperado**, para ello estoy haciendo uso del `isset()` pero no me da el resultado que esperaba.

A continuacion dejo dicha **funcion:**

```
 function familiar_actualizar($familiar){
                 if (is_array($familiar)) {
                   if (
                    isset($familiar['id']) and
                    isset($familiar['nombre']) and
                    isset($familiar['apellido_1']) and
                    isset($familiar['apellido_2']) and
                    isset($familiar['fecha_nacimiento']) and
                    isset($familiar['fecha_fallecimiento']) and
                    isset($familiar['lugar_nacimiento']) and
                    isset($familiar['lugar_fallecimiento']) and
                    isset($familiar['oficio']) and
                    isset($familiar['datos_destacables']) and
                    isset($familiar['biografia']) and
                    isset($familiar['create_at'])
                  ) {
                      return "composicion SI CORRECTA del array";
                  }


                  else{
                    return "composicion NO CORRECTA del array";
                  }

                 }
                 else{
                  return "no es un array";
                 }



          }
```

Para probar la **funcion** he creado el siguiente **array**:

```
  $familiar = array(
    'id' =>  8,
    'nombre' =>  'paco' ,
    'apellido_1' =>  'ramirez' ,
    'apellido_2' =>  'bezolla' ,
    'fecha_nacimiento' => null,
    'fecha_fallecimiento' => null,
    'lugar_nacimiento' =>  'korea del norte' ,
    'lugar_fallecimiento' =>  'korea del sur' ,
    'oficio' =>  'carpintero' ,
    'datos_destacables' =>  'era un tio muy gracioso' ,
    'biografia' =>  'un dia nacio y otro dia mnurio' ,
    'create_at' =>  '2019-06-20 10:33:49'
  );
```

**Finalmente,** le paso por parametro a la funcion el **array** que he creado de prueba:

```
echo  familiar_actualizar($familiar);
```

> Le hago un `echo` para que muestre el resultado del return.

Me **deberia** mostrar :

> composicion SI CORRECTA del array

Ya que respeta **los campos requeridos del array esperado** pero en vez de eso me devuelve :

> composicion NO CORRECTA del array

Answer (score 1, accepted):

El problema esta, en que la funcion `isset` retornará False si el valor enviado es `null`.

Y como en el `if` compruebas de que todos los campos esten definidos, al enviar `null` uno de ellos dara `False` lo cual avanzara el `else`. En vez de nulo envia un `string` vacío.

"Devuelve TRUE si var existe y tiene un valor distinto de `NULL`, `FALSE` de lo contrario."

[Documentación](https://www.php.net/manual/es/function.isset.php)

Answer (score 0):

Por lo visto no puedo poner `null` a las fechas, cambia sus valores de `null` a `''` tal que asi :

```
 $familiar = array(
    'id' =>  8,
    'nombre' =>  'paco' ,
    'apellido_1' =>  'ramirez' ,
    'apellido_2' =>  'bezolla' ,
    'fecha_nacimiento' => '',
    'fecha_fallecimiento' => '',
    'lugar_nacimiento' =>  'korea del norte' ,
    'lugar_fallecimiento' =>  'korea del sur' ,
    'oficio' =>  'carpintero' ,
    'datos_destacables' =>  'era un tio muy gracioso' ,
    'biografia' =>  'un dia nacio y otro dia mnurio' ,
    'create_at' =>  '2019-06-20 10:33:49'
  );
```

Y finalmente se arreglo.